# How do I install known_host keys for ssh manually?

Tags: ssh

I've got a secure transmission system where I'm pushing host keys to a database and I'm trying to install keys generated on a Ubuntu 15 machines and install them them on a SLES 11 machine and I'm trying to install keys generated on a Centos 7 machine on that Ubuntu 15 machine.

So, is there a common mechanism for each of these machines to install host keys,  this is getting really confusing and I'm thinking I'm being a bit over scrupulous.  Everything is supposed to be automated and I'm figured out a decent method for collecting the keys, I just don't know where the right place to put them on the machine

Here's a key on the centos machine:

`[root@centos ~]# cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBIl8BT33T4sEAgG56CItPWep/N3IKaUaw8Xy6Fn6k9SLsARi9zZk9FAd6H6DfbIxzkz1sjSjfq1JSVyd3slKf4M=`

and here's what it looks like when I import it (via ssh manually accepting it) in my knownhosts on my ubuntu machine

`root@ubuntu:/home# cat aaron/.ssh/known_hosts
|1|F+Hr+T8eulEpFFFhwdJKdcOg6yQ=|yM/XLEkDPFUWO/g9vPOONBkRvtE= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBIl8BT33T4sEAgG56CItPWep/N3IKaUaw8Xy6Fn6k9SLsARi9zZk9FAd6H6DfbIxzkz1sjSjfq1JSVyd3slKf4M=`

So, it looks like the first part is in the known_hosts file is something encrypted and on the SLES machines, that part is not encrypted, so it's a bit simpler.

So my questions are

1. How do I come up with that encrypted part so I can echo it in to the known_hosts file?
2. How do I know if a given linux system is expecting the first hunk to be encrypted?

Answer (score 6):

Manual page for `sshd` describes format of the file:

> **SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS FILE FORMAT**
>
> The `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts` files contain host public keys for all known hosts.  The global file should be prepared by the administrator (optional), and the per-user file is maintained automatically: whenever the user connects from an unknown host, its key is added to the per-user file.
>
> Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers (optional), **hostnames**, bits, exponent, modulus, comment.  The fields are separated by spaces.
>
> [...]
>
> Alternately, **hostnames may be stored in a hashed form** which hides host names and addresses should the file's contents be disclosed.  Hashed hostnames start with a ‘|’ character.  Only one hashed hostname may appear on a single line and none of the above negation or wildcard operators may be applied.

Except the part `bits, exponent, modulus` is now used together as public key. The hostname is hashed, but you can write it as a string and then run `ssh-keygen` over the file:

> `ssh-keygen -H [-f known_hosts_file]`

for example `ssh-keygen -H -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: Better answer than mine, but see also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56268/ssh-benefits-of-using-hashed-known-hosts for more on hashed host names.

Comment: I am trying to teach people to read manual pages, but so far no progress :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandate to keep your `hostname` encrypted

```
192.168.0.105 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBIl8BT33T4sEAgG56CItPWep/N3IKaUaw8Xy6Fn6k9SLsARi9zZk9FAd6H6DfbIxzkz1sjSjfq1JSVyd3slKf4M=
```